# Is there a way to have camera follow g-force in Unity 3D (versioon 2019.3.15f1)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, plane

I am making a game where at one point the player flies a plane/spaceship, and was wondering if there is a way for the camera to move slightly up when the player flies down, and vice versa, same for left and right so that it might make it feel better to play, and slightly more realistic then just a static camera movement.

Thanks a lot !

PS: Beginner here, so sorry if it's an obvious answer...

Comment: You can absolutely write a script to do that. Are you asking for an example?

Comment: @NSJacob1 Yes, if you have one, it would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unity Standard Assets script CameraFollowsPlayer (Not sure of the name but it is something like this) and you drag and drop your character to your new Camera. It should do the trick with the delay movements. Alternatively you could use Lerp and transform Cameras Position in LateUpdate() method.

Comment: I can't seem to find the Standard asset script you're talking about, so I tried out the Lerp and transform Camera Position in LateUpdate() method, quite jittery though....

Comment: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/asset-packs/standard-assets-for-unity-2017-3-32351

Comment: Ohhh, I though Standard asset script were the ones included with unity, well, sorry for my little experience with unity, and thankyou very much for being so patient !